# Force SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 32bit instead of 64bit in Windows 7-64

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, shdocvw

I'm using SHDocVw.InternetExplorer to open an IE window and control the session.
Mostly to automate going to a certain page, logging in, checking for certain data, etc.

It works great, except that we're supposed to be using this internet explorer add-on extension now, and when my program spawns the window most of the add-ons aren't listed under Tools->Manage Add-Ons

Is there anything I can try to load in at least this one extension?

**Edit:**
Ok, So I think I may have narrowed down what's going on. when launched normally IE launches in 32bit mode.

When it's spawned using SHDocVw, it loads 64bit. When I go to the start menu and launch Internet Explorer (64-bit) the add on is missing also. **So now I need to figure out how to force 32 bit IE when spawning from the program that's targeted to 64bit.**

Comment: Is the extension you seek there when you launch IE normally?

Comment: Yeah it is. I tried adding the extensions DLL to the project, but I don't know how to put it into the spawned window from there...

Comment: It could be that the registration was done in a low integrity registry location, so normal IE, which runs as a low integrity process, sees it.  You're probably launching your app with the default integrity level, the IE COM object inherits that, and it doesn't see the registration.  You could try forcing your app to run as low integrity to see if this solves the issue, then you know the registration is wonky.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625960.aspx

Comment: So I started Process explorer, then started IE from the Quick Launch bar and it showed medium integrity. Then I started IE from my app and it showed up as low integrity. So that makes me think that the plug-in was installed in medium integrity and now that my app is starting IE in low, it doesn't see it (and a bunch of other add-ons that would normally come up). Oh, and my app is running in medium integrity in case that makes a difference. I am just learing about integrity levels for the first time today...

Comment: So I think the real problem is that the program is targeting 64bit, but the add-on only works with 32bit IE. I need to see if there is a way (besides targeting only x86) to force 32bit IE.

Comment: I think you just need to use the right context flag when calling CoCreateInstance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693716(v=vs.85).aspx, e.g. CLSCTX_ACTIVATE_32_BIT_SERVER.

Comment: I saw that. Unfortunately VB.net doesn't have CoCreateInstance. Ive read that it has something similar called activate.createinstance, but I haven't seen a way to flag it as create 32 bit version or whatever. I may just have to suck it up and target 32bit

Comment: I don't know much about VB, sorry.  You could open a separate question on that and I bet someone here will know.  The general approach everyone has taken for the last five years has been to just target 32bit IE, which is why all the add-ons don't have 64bit versions.  :)

Comment: Cruel irony. No one uses the 64bit, and so no 64bit add on for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to just target 32bit mode until I figure out how to only target 32bit IE from within a 64bit program.