# I cannot create a new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer

Consider the following peice of code :

```
If (ias.WebBrowser Is Nothing) Then
    ias.WebBrowser = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
End If
waitTing(1)
```

It produces the following error :

> "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))."  String

Where is the problem?

Interesting: I can't open internet explorer at all. How do I reinstall it?

Comment: what version of the browser were you using? and what OS?

Comment: windows 7. I just downloaded

Comment: "possibly" it might be an issue due to the bit-ness (64 or 32) of the IE version and Windows you are using. Here's something you can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223833/force-shdocvw-internetexplorer-32bit-instead-of-64bit-in-windows-7-64